# Print with blank first page?

Tags: printing

I frequently have to print a 3-page document.  Wanting to save paper, I print it 2-to-a-page, double-sided.  So I end up with the front having "1 | 2", and the back having "3 |  ".

It'd be more convenient if the front had " | 1", and the back had "2 | 3".  Is there a way to have Mac OS X printing insert a blank page at the start when printing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm probably not the way you want it. You don't mention what are you trying to print (Word? Pages? TextEdit?), If you use Pages, for example,  you could create a template that inserts a page break in the 1st page (at the beginning), so your real 1st page would be the 2nd page. Then use that template as your "blank document".

I know, simple solution but works ;)

**UPDATE** Since you need to usually add a blank page to a PDF, you can use preview for that. Position yourself in the first page and do an:

Edit -> Insert Blank Page

[image]

Comment: It's never a document I made, so a template with a blank first page is a good idea but not really an option here.  Usually it's a PDF (from Preview), or a .doc (from LibreOffice).  In the latter case, I can insert a page-break before printing, but I don't think Preview can do that.

Comment: Yes, preview can do that, open the PDF in question and go to Edit -> Insert Blank Page

Comment: Wow, I totally missed that.  (Maybe because it's oddly dimmed in some cases, like when a .doc is open.)  Thanks!